# C# WPF: How can i access properties of a bound object for styling?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid

I have a DataGrid with 12 columns which all need to be styled according to object data (several different background, foreground and Border Values).

Currently i have 12 nearly identlical blocks of code like this:

```xml
<materialDesign:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Jan" Header="Jan" Binding="{Binding Aps[0].CellValue}">
    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell" BasedOn="{StaticResource dgc}">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding Aps[0].ToolTipText}" />
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource contextMenu}" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Aps[0].CellBackground}" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding Aps[0].CellForeground}" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{Binding Aps[0].CellBorderBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{Binding Aps[0].CellBorderThickness}" />

            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Aps[0].CellBackground}" />
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding Aps[0].CellForeground}" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource tb}" />
    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
</materialDesign:DataGridTextColumn>
```

The objects are all stored within a Collection within the "row object" so i have to access them by their indexes.

My Question is if it is possible to convert this into a style resource and only bind the cell object once?

I tried like everything i found on google but found no working solution for this.

Comment: what does change between to different copies of this? just the [index]?
You should be able to just put this into the resources of your parent and then reference it like this: 
<materialDesign:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Jan" Header="Jan" Binding="{Binding Aps[0]}">
<Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding CellBackground}" />

Comment: Yes just the index changes but when i try to put it in ressources and just reference the properties without "aps[0]" i get not found in "row object" binding errors

Comment: Make the column binding like this `Binding="{Binding Aps[0]}"` and create a `DataTemplate` that contains a `TextBox` which has it's `Text` property bound to `CellValue`. Next you can remove all the `Aps[x]` from your bindings and bind directly to properties in your style.

Comment: You must also modify the binding paths inside the Style and reference the CellValue property. When `<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Aps[0]}">` then bindings would look like e.g. `<Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding CellValue.CellBackground}" />`.